Unable to handle .isPresent() while creating Juint test cases
if (clientDetailsRepository.findIDByClientName(clientDetailRequest.getClientName()).isPresent()) {
            return CommonUtils.getResponseObject(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, req,
                    "Client with Client Name " + clientDetailRequest.getClientName() + " is already present",
                    false);
        }

while writing the Junit test case for the following :
@Test
public void setClientDetailsTest() {
    Optional<Long> opt = Optional.of(20l);
    when(clientDetailsRepository.findIDByClientName(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(opt);
            ResponseEntity<Object> response =  clientService.setClientDetails(req,ClientDetails());
        assertNotNull(response);
    }
    

What I have observed is that isPresent() is always returning false and it is never going inside if Statement

Hi, welcome on Stack Overflow. Your question is not complete and misses a few pieces of information - how do you pass clientDetailsRepository to clientService, how req is initialized etc.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you were lucky to have an answer this time. Very often we can help only with a [mre], so please see if you can supply one in your next question. Thanks.

I think the issue is related to ArgumentMatcher. So try to pass the correct value, not a matcher. Example:
@Test
public void setClientDetailsTest() {
    String clientName = "testClient";
    ClientDetailRequest clientDetailRequest = new ClientDetailRequest();
    clientDetailRequest.setClientName(clientName);

    Optional<Long> opt = Optional.of(20L);
    when(clientDetailsRepository.findIDByClientName(clientDetailRequest.getClientName())).thenReturn(opt);

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = clientService.setClientDetails(req, clientDetailRequest);

    assertNotNull(response);
}

